# Problems when making a variable public

Tags: c#, variables, public

I have some problems understanding when a variable is `public` and can be accessed by other classes and when not. Right now, I am getting the error that the `run` variable in `Menu()` isn't declared. I have tried putting a "public" in front of the declaration, but this just gave me tons of errors. How do I make the `run` declaration in `Main` public?

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var run = 0;
    Menu();
}

static void Menu()
{
    run++;

    if (run <= 1) {
        Welcome();
    }
}
```

I have tried to find a solution, but didn't find any, although someone for sure asked the same thing. Btw, the `Main` and `Menu` function look like they could be merged, but provide me with a useful workaround for another part of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make all variables `public`, like the local variable `run` in your example. Access modifiers only apply to class variables (so called *fields*) that are declared **outside** of a method:

```
public class Test 
{
    public static int run = 0;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Menu();
    }

    static void Menu()
    {
        run++;

        if (run <= 1) {
            Welcome();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will accept the answer as soon as stack overflow allows me to. Have a nice day!

Comment: Of course, one should wonder about making that field public in the first place. If the aim is to enable `Menu` to use the field, there is no reason to make the field public at all. If you want another _class_ to be able to access the field, it needs to be internal or public, but normally you want to keep it private.

Answer (score 0):

`run` would be declared as a property of your class:

```
class YourClass
{
    public static int run = 0;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Menu();
    }

    static void Menu()
    {
        run++;
        if (run <= 1) {
            Welcome();
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: what you have in your example isnt a property

Answer (score 0):

Variables outside their scope are not accessible. That means outside the block (inside the braces) where they are defined (to keep it simple). So you can access `run` only in sub blocks like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var run = 0;
    {
        run++;
        if (run <= 1) {
            Welcome();
    }
}
```

Another way is to make the variable part of the class - then it becomes a field, which are usually private:

```
public class Program 
{
    private static int run;
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        run = 0;
        Menu();
    }

    static void Menu()
    {
        run++;

        if (run <= 1) {
            Welcome();
        }
    }
}
```

I you want to do object oriented programming, you could encapsulate this in a class:

```
public class Program 
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.Run = 0;
        myClass.Menu();
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public int Run { get; set; }

    public void Menu()
    {
        Run++;

        if (Run <= 1) {
            Welcome();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. next time you can edit this obvious mistake.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of answers to your problem. But what you are lacking is the understanding of [Variable and Method Scope in Microsoft .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx).

Below is an excerpt from said article (Sorry about the VB.Net reference, but it still applies).

**Scope of Variables** - You can declare variables at four different locations in your programs. Where you choose to declare variables determines the scope.

- **Block** - If you declare a variable within a block construct such as an `If` statement, that variable's scope is only until the end of the block. The lifetime is until the procedure ends.

---

- **Procedure** - If you declare a variable within a procedure, but outside of any `If` statement, the scope is until the `End Sub` or `End Function`. The lifetime of the variable is until the procedures ends.

---

- **Module/Class** - You can declare a variable outside of any procedure, but it must be within a `Class…End Class` or `Module…End Module` statement. The scope is any procedure within this module. The lifetime for a variable defined within a class is until the object is cleaned up by the garbage collector. The lifetime for a variable defined within a module is until the program ends.

---

- **Project** - You can declare a `Public` variable within a `Module…End Module` statement, and that variable's scope will be any procedure or method within the project. The lifetime of the variable will be until the program ends.